# Not able to interact with metamask from metamask mobile browser using web3js

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, mobile-wallet

Iam connecting to metamask and sending transactions(trc20) using my desktop web browser. Its working perfectly.
But in mobile, metamask browser or native android browsers is not detecting metamask or any window.ethereum object.
This is the basic code Im using,

```
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Wallet is installed!');
    } else {
        alert('Metamask Wallet is not installed!');
        return
    }
```

I'm getting wallet not installed message.

I tried many other ways from various other threads and still not able to interact with metamask.

I also checked the deeplinking part but no help.

When I initialise like,

`const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);`

I'm able to do,

```
const value = web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether')
```

It gives me converted value.

But still window.ethereum is showing as undefined

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Depending on where you're trying to use window.ethereum, you might be calling it before it is actually injected. Have a look at the docs (https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-provider-api) and try to check for it using the async snippet through `detectEthereumProvider()`

Comment: Already tried that. I waited for the object to get injected(as mentioned in docs). But still the same issue persists

Comment: @razgraf Can you tell me how to implement metamask interaction with web3js on metamask mobile browser ( browser which is inbuilt in metamask ). I tried waiting till it is injected as mentioned in docs.

Comment: If the browser extension manages to connect to your website I don't see why the mobile metamask browser would have a problem with it. I suggest trying to debug using the example code given in those docs (https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#using-the-provider). An alternative if you don't figure it out is to rely on an already existing implementation, something like useDapp.io

Answer (score 1):

when you have the metamask *extension* installed in your browser, `window.ethereum` will return a valid object, but in mobile browsers, you can't  install extensions. The issue is not your code, it's how the code works and it works with browsers that have the extension installed such as your desktop browsers, e.g chrome, mozilla, e.t.c.

Comment: So you are telling that it wont work in mobile browsers or metamask mobile app built in browser???

Comment: mobile browsers

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement metamask interaction with web3js on metamask mobile browser ( browser which is inbuilt in metamask )

Comment: const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider)